# some characterizations of entire functions to be a polynomial

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Then under which conditions will $f$ be a polynomial? How to prove under either of the following conditions, $f$ is polynomial?

(1). $|f(z)|>1$ whenever $|z|>1$;

(2). there exists $M>0$ and $\{R_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $R_n>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n=\infty$ with $f(z)\neq 0$ whenever $|z|=R_n$, and for all $n$,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{|z|=R_n}|\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}||dz|<M.
\end{equation*}

How to prove? I plan to use something like Argument principle but do not know how to apply... THanks

Comment: Hint: Both conditions (combined with the knowledge that f has no pole) allow you to show that the number of zeros of f is finite.

Answer (score 0):

1) implies, that each zero of $f$ is inside the unit ball. In case there would be an accumulation point of zeros, $f$ would be identically zero, contradicting 1). Hence the number of zeros is finite. Moreover, each zero has finite order (write down the taylor expansion of $f$ in such a point to see this)

2) if $\gamma$ is the boundary of a bounded starshaped region $D$ in the complex plane and $f$ is meromorphic with no zero along $\gamma$, the integral 
$$I_\gamma = \int_\gamma \frac{f^\prime(z)}{f(z)} dz$$
is, up to a factor of $2i\pi$, the difference of the number of zeros of $f$ in $D$ and the number of poles in $D$ (this is a well known consequence of the residue theorem which you will find in any textbook on complex analysis).

By assumption, there are no poles in $\mathbb{C}$, and the integral is bounded on a set of circles with radius going off to infinity -- this is what the estimate in 2) tells you. Hence you get a bound on the number of zeros of $f$, again.

A holomorphic function with a finite number of zeros is a polynomial.

(If this last statement is not clear to you: assume the zeros are $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ with multiplicity $n_i$. Then look at $$ p(z) =  \Pi_i (z-z_i)^{n_i}$$
This is holomorphic with the same set of zeros as $f$. Now consider $\frac{f}{p}$ and show it is bounded near the zeros of $f$, which implies it is holomorphic without any zero and hence constant).

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter: if you thinks the answer is incorrect or contains an error, you should point this out in a comment. This would be helpful for everyone interested in the question, and for me as well. Just downvoting will not reveal any potential error.

Comment: Prof. Thomas's solution is not correct: it is holomorphic without any zero and hence constant. A holomorphic function without zero may not be constant

Comment: @RenShiquan: Hello Ren, thank you for sharing your observation. But, first of all, I'm not a professor, secondly, I do not understand your comment, neither can I see where an error would be. You asked how to show that $f$ has to be a polynomial. That I did. If it turns out to be constant it is still a polnomial, but condition 1) does not imply constancy. (Take $f(z) = z$). Finally, any (entire) holomorphic function without a zero is well known to be constant, I do not understand what that part of your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: @RenShiquan: I had a bit more time now to look into this. I guess you complain about the sentence from my response which you cited. Note first, that I do assume that you know that an entire holomorphic function with finitely many zeros is a polynomial. I just added a sketch how to do that in case you don't. Secondly, the function we are talking about here is entire, that is, holomorphic on the whole complex plane. For such a function the statement is true. In case you don't believe that I'd like to ask you to give me a counterexample.